# How does getchar() work in a While loop?

Tags: c, getchar

This part of a program confused me when I'm working in an exercise book.

Why do I get the same result when I swap the last `if` statement and `while getchar()`?

In both cases I get the sentence `"Enter the next title."` first. And in both cases I get `getchar()` second, waiting for an input with the cursor blinking.

Shouldn't putting the `while(getchar()!= '\n'); continue;` First make the program wait for an input before printing `puts("Enter the next title.");`?

My understanding that it should be stuck inside while loop until the condition of exit is present, then proceed to the next statement! which is the print

Here the if statement first:

```
while(count< MAXBKS && s_gets(library[count].title,MAXTITL) != NULL && library[count].title[0] != '\0')
    {
        puts("Now enter the author.");
        s_gets(library[count].author,MAXAUTL);
        puts("Now enter the value.");
        scanf("%f", &library[count++].value);
        if( count < MAXBKS)  //  1  //
            puts("Enter the next title.");
        while(getchar()!= '\n')  //  2  //
            continue;

    }
```

here the the `while(getchar()..` first:

```
while(count< MAXBKS && s_gets(library[count].title,MAXTITL) != NULL && library[count].title[0] != '\0')
{
    puts("Now enter the author.");
    s_gets(library[count].author,MAXAUTL);
    puts("Now enter the value.");
    scanf("%f", &library[count++].value);
    while(getchar()!= '\n')  //   2  //
        continue;

    if( count < MAXBKS)    //   1  //
        puts("Enter the next title.");
}
```

Here is the entire program for context:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXTITL 40
#define MAXAUTL 40
#define MAXBKS 10

char * s_gets(char * st, int n);
struct book
{
    char title[MAXTITL];
    char author[MAXAUTL];
    float value;
};


int main(void)
{
    struct book library[MAXBKS];
    int count = 0;
    int index, filecount;
    FILE *pbooks;
    int size = sizeof(struct book);

    if ((pbooks = fopen("book.dat", "a+b")) == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Can't open book.dat file\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    rewind(pbooks);
    while(count< MAXBKS && fread(&library[count],size,1, pbooks) == 1)
    {
        if (count ==0)
            puts("Current contents of book.dat:");
        printf("%s by %s: $%.2f\n", library[count].title, library[count].author, library[count].value);
        count++;
    }
    filecount = count;
    if(count == MAXBKS)
    {
        fputs("The book.dat file is full.\n", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }
    puts("Please add new book titles.");
    puts("Press [enter] at the start of a line to stop.\n");
    while(count< MAXBKS && s_gets(library[count].title,MAXTITL) != NULL && library[count].title[0] != '\0')
    {
        puts("Now enter the author.");
        s_gets(library[count].author,MAXAUTL);
        puts("Now enter the value.");
        scanf("%f", &library[count++].value);
        while(getchar()!= '\n')
            continue;

        if( count < MAXBKS)
            puts("Enter the next title.");
    }
    if(count>0)
    {
        puts("Here is a list of your books:");
        for(index =0; index < count; index++)
            printf("%s by %s: $%.2f\n", library[index].title, library[index].author, library[index].value);
        fwrite(&library[filecount],size,1,pbooks);
    }
    else
        puts("No books? Too bad.\n");
    puts("Bye.\n");
    fclose(pbooks);
    return(0);
}


char *s_gets(char *st, int n)
{
    char *ret_val;
    char *find;

    ret_val= fgets(st,n,stdin);
    if (ret_val)
    {
        find = strchr(st, '\n');
        if(find)
            *find = '\0';
        else
            while(getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
        }
        return (ret_val);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with `getchar`. Why do you need it at all?

Comment: @CareyGregory its to hold the bigger while loop until the new input is entered. my question is why does the puts statement after the while(getchar() gets executed before the exit condition of the while loop?

Comment: That "continue" is inside the inner while loop itself; it has no effect on the outer one.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker ok, i see, my question still is; "why the Puts statement is printed before the while continue getchar loop finishes?"

Comment: 1. Check the return value of `scanf`. 2. Change your loop to `while((c=getchar()) != '\n') { printf("read: %d\n",c); continue}` to see what `getchar` is consuming. 3. @LeeDanielCrocker is right, the `continue` only affects the inner loop, so the "waiting for user input" might be not in the `getchar` but in `s_gets`, you just don't realize it.

Comment: The loop exits because `getchar` finds the newline immediately and therefore exits the loop (`scanf` didn't consume the newline).

Comment: Note that the `while (getchar() != '\n')` loop is not safe if there's an EOF around.  You should use `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)`, noting that `c` needs to be an `int` and not a `char` (because `getchar()` returns an `int` and not a `char`, despite its name).\ . Most likely, you won't run into trouble.  If you do, you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't putting the `while(getchar()!= '\n'); continue;` first make the program wait for an input before printing `puts("Enter the next title.");`?

No, `while(getchar()!= '\n'); continue;` will clear the input buffer<sup>1</sup>, it will
not wait for user input. Then it will print the text. The reason why it doesn't
wait for the user to enter something is that you had a `scanf` before. If it
matches a float, it will convert that and save in `&library[count++].value`,
however the newline will be left in the input buffer. That's why people use this
method of clearing the rest in the input buffer. If it doesn't match anything,
then the whole line will remain in the input buffer.

For this reason it doesn't matter which you execute first, the buffer will be
cleared and your text will be printed. It is the `fgets` in the next `s_gets()`
call which blocks and waits for user input, not the `getchar()`.

> My understanding that it should be stuck inside while loop until the condition of exit is present,
>   then proceed to the next statement! which is the print

And so it did, you most likely misinterpreted who blocks and waits for the
user input.

Some suggestions:

The clearing of the buffer is best done like this:

```
int c;
while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Also it is better to always check the return value of `scanf`. It will return
the number of successfull matches tokens. So if you expect one conversion, then
check that `scanf` returns 1. If that's not the case, the input was wrong. You
may decide to clear the buffer and let the user enter retry again.

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously if the first reading code would be the `while(getchar() != '\n') continue;` then it would block and wait for user input, because the input buffer will be empty. But in your case, the input buffer is definitively not empty.

Comment: It'd be even better to use `fgets` and `strtod` and not use `scanf` at all.  Which would conveniently also remove the confusing behavior where there's a trailing \n left behind in the input buffer.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I decided not to change the OPs code too much.